# Chart plotting algorithms?

Tags: php, algorithm, charts

I am looking to plot charts using the PHP image create, what kind of algorithms are used to transform my terrible chart:

[image]

Into something better like:

[image]

and

[image]

How can I make the lines of my chart smooth and pretty like the 2 charts above?

**edit:** I don't want to use any library, I am trying to do this myself.

Comment: You could do all of this on your own, or are you looking for a library? What you consider smooth is generally called "antialiasing"

Comment: @Jasper: I am trying to do it myself.

Comment: Then have a look at internet sources about antialiasing. But it will be hard...

Comment: I needed to make antialiasing but for an ASCII Art plot. To do this I calculate the slope between `point N` and `point N + 1` and I plot the segment bewteen these 2 points. Hope it can help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this best think, I use these charts all the time

http://www.highcharts.com

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying t understand myself how the algorithm of smoothing the lines work.

Comment: and OP is not asking about JS, but creating static images.

Answer (score 1):

For "smoothing the lines", you have to refer to external sources about antialiasing (or let PHP do this part, [see manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imageantialias.php))

Then, you need to have an idea how exactly your graph should look like:

- axis (scaling, labeling, ...)
- grid (with differend line width for major and minor segments?)
- representation of data (points, straight lines, smooth lines [getting rather hard again here])
- description

And I think each point could be a quite well suited coding exercise. But without more specific questions, I can't help you better.